# New FBSDK 4.0+ , log in or share using access token

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, fbsdk

I am using new FBSDK. Able to get access token generated by FBSDK using

```
[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]tokenString]
```

How can I use this to share or post without prompting user to login again?

Scenario : User Logs in via Facebook, access token gets generated, we store this access token in defaults. User shares something for this session. For future sessions when user wants to share something we use access token stored inside defaults for posting.

Please correct me if I am not getting function of access tokens...

Comment: Isnt it one time login ? The user shouldnt be logged out unless he clicks on logout button.  Can you please mention the scenario where you want to store the token

Comment: @Mr.T : edited adding scenario.please check

Comment: @BhushanVU check my ans...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method:

```
- (void)continueSystemLogInWithTokenString:(NSString *)oauthToken error:(NSError *)accountStoreError state:(FBSDKLoginManagerSystemAccountState *)state;
```

Where `oauthToken` is your `accessToken` String

Once you have app token, you can do this:

```
if (oauthToken) {
    completer = [[FBSDKLoginSystemAccountCompleter alloc] initWithTokenString:oauthToken appID:[FBSDKSettings appID]];
    }
```

Note: **All these methods are defined in FBSDKLoginCompletion class.**

**Call Heirarchy:**

This method:

`initWithTokenString`  in `FBSDKLoginCompletion.m` is called in `continueSystemLogInWithTokenString` in `FBSDKLoginManager.m`

and `continueSystemLogInWithTokenString` is called in `performSystemLogIn` method in `FBSDKLoginManager`.

`performSystemLogIn` is called from `beginSystemLogIn` in `FBSDKLoginManager`.

`beginSystemLogIn` is called from `logInWithBehavior`  in `FBSDKLoginManager`.

`logInWithBehavior` is called from following places:

- `logInWithPermissions`     in `FBSDKLoginManager`
- `fallbackToNativeBehavior` in `FBSDKLoginManager`
- `attemptBrowserLogIn` in `FBSDKLoginCompletion`
- `completeLogIn`  in `FBSDKLoginCompletion`

Comment: can you please explain where and how I can use - (void)continueSystemLogInWithTokenString:(NSString *)oauthToken error:(NSError *)accountStoreError state:(FBSDKLoginManagerSystemAccountState *)state; method?

Comment: It will be too long to post the answer with the call heiraarchy. You can go into FBSDKLoginCOmpletion and look for the method initWithTokenString, and right click on it and select find call heirarchy. You can see who is calling it on left side of xcode. You can follow that hierarchy deep down and implement it as per your need.

Answer (score 1):

check Permission like this...don't store access token...following code  use you don't need everytime login...

```
  if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]hasGranted:@"email"])
   {
      // add your coding here after login call this block
   }
   else
   {

//login code

    FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

    [loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)




  }];

   }
```